# OpenGL VBO handles

Tags: opengl

Is it safe to pass integer handles to multiple VBO's that I create to other classes to use?

My main Class creates a bunch of handles with gllenbuffers.
I then pass these handles down to sub-classes and store them in variables in that class.
Inside that class is where data is actually uploaded via glbufferdata.

Is this okay?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, why not? As you already mentioned handles are just integers.

Comment: It's fine, or you could create a class wrapping the VBO (or multiple VBOs). That way you can better control their lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

The integer handles are just names that OpenGL uses to uniquely identify the VBOs, so yes. The problem some people run into is when there are multiple OpenGL contexts and you use a VBO from one context in another context, in which that VBO doesn't exist.

Just make sure you have a plan of knowing which element will clean up the handle when you are done using them without leaving other objects with names for invalid VBOs.

Comment: That's definitely a valid concern, but the namespace for certain types of objects (the types that actually store data) such as Buffer Objects and Texture Objects can be shared if you create the contexts correctly. Low-level APIs like WGL and GLX let you do this when you create your context, and higher-level frameworks (e.g. Qt, GLFW) usually let you pass a handle to another context to share resources with.

Comment: Good point. I work with iOS a lot and we can similarly create "ShareGroups" of OpenGL contexts which can share VBOs, textures, etc. Proper data sharing between contexts can lead to difficult to track down problems.